# Android Multiple Device Development

Tags: android, device

I am new to programming in general and have been teaching myself using Android SDK in Eclipse.   Lately I have had a lot of iPhone developers telling me to ditch Android and go to iPhone because it is simply too hard to develop for the whole spectrum of Android devices.

When I look at the dev guide, I see a page about developing for multiple screens, and it seems pretty straight forward.

Has anyone had a hard time developing for multiple devices on the Android platform?

Comment: " *I have had a lot of iPhone developers telling me to ditch Android and go to iPhone because it is simply too hard to develop for the whole spectrum of Android devices* " - Had any of them actually tried?

Comment: I personally haven't, but I've worked with a team of other iPhone devs who developed a simple AV app for both, stating that the fragmentation in the Android platform became too costly in time and energy to develop for and maintain. Just my $0.02.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Developing for multiple screens can be a bit weird, especially after the iPhone, where there is only one screen to worry about.  Read up on the [AndroidMainfest.xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) file, which describes how to limit deployment to certain hardware features.

Once you've decided what you target hardware is, have a look at the [multiple screen guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) again, make sure to pay attention to the difference between "px," "dp," and "sp."  After that, I have found certain things will not EXACLTY look the same across different resolutions, but I've accepted that (but I think you can target resolution if you need to also).

In the end, it depends on how much time and effort you're willing to give it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit hard to answer. The main problem is what you try to do. If you do a game, I am sure you can do it good on both systems.

If you want to access some basic functions of android like calendar, contacts and more, you might find some pitfalls, where you need some tricks to make it work on some devices.

You should consider more than just the multiple device question. Whats your preferred programming language, can you life in a closed system under the market control of apple, on what platform do you have more fun?

My personal decision was very easy: I prefer android because I don't have a mac, I don't want a mac and I am seriously too dumb to handle the Mac OS...

And like my mother said about the iPad Touch of my dad: "Why does it only have one button?" :)

Seriously, if you have a mac and you are familiar with it, give iPhone a try and decide for yourself...

Answer (score 0):

There is a some work involved supporting multiple screen sizes but i cannot see any reason why you should drop android development because of it.  Think of it as this simple equation :)

```
String moreScreenTypes = morePhones = morePotentialUsers = moreMoney
```

Comment: developing in android is much easier as compared to iphone. objective c vs java ...java is easier to learn n start development

Comment: I think an Object is more realistic than a String

Answer (score 0):

Like @Warren said, a lot depends on your language of choice and development platform of choice.

If you like Java and Eclipse, try your hand at Android. No harm in gaining experience.

If you have a Mac and use Xcode, familiarize yourself with Objective-C and the iOS SDK.

There's no reason you can't eventually do both, but the important thing is to keep your momentum learning at least one and then worry about adapting once you've stretched your developer legs. Coding in multiple languages will gain you a new appreciation for programming. You'll start to better understand fundamental concepts like grammar, architecture, programming paradigms, data structures, algorithms, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Had once a problem, developed a tab host app with different web views on every tab, and the information had been loaded from different websites. THen i injected each page with some scrips and web pages looked a bit different, so i had to support the initial scale of a web page for different devices, since i have decided to develop for almost every device out there. Then I had a problem of calculating more or less common scaling constant for different groups of devices that i have divided into by myself using some primitive calculations, common sense and visual outlook